# Use Oracle APEX LOVs to Initialize Multiple Page Items? - APEX 21.1

Tags: oracle-apex

I understand that the default behavior of LOVs is the following:

```sql
SELECT business_desc as display_val,
       business_id as return_val
  FROM businesses
```

This attached to a select type page item `P1_BUSINESS` will display a list and when a list row is selected, then assign the `business_id` value to the page item `P1_BUSINESS`.

Is there a way to build a list of values to set the value of more than one page item that are not displayed? Using the below SQL:

```sql
SELECT business_desc as display_val,
       business_id as return_val,
       form_type,
       individual_flag
  FROM businesses
```

Where now when a user selects something from `P1_BUSINESS` it sets the values of that row/record as follows:

- `P1_BUSINESS = business_id` (like it does by default)
- `P1_FORM_TYPE = form_type` (`P1_FORM_TYPE` is a hidden page item)
- `P1_IND_FLAG = individual_flag` (`P1_IND_FLAG` is a hidden page item)

I know I can do this with an `onchange` dynamic action, but just curious if can do inside the LOV or select page item (`P1_BUSINESS`) declaratively.

Comment: The normal "List of values" component does not have such a feature, however, the popup lov does have it. Search for apex lov additional outputs - there are several blogs showing how this works.

Comment: Yes, i saw them, but based on what I've read I was under the impression you need to 'Display' those other fields as well. Assuming this is not the case? Will dig further into popup LOVs. Thx.

Comment: No, you can set the "Visible" attribute to "No" for any additional columns. That way you'll just see the regular display value but when selecting it will pick up the additional ones too.

Comment: feel free to add as an answer and i will give credit thx...

Comment: Will do in the morning - no time now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Shared Components > List Of Values, there is an attribute "Additional Display Columns". The help text on that screen says it all *Additional display columns can be defined for item types that support multiple display columns, for example the Popup LOV. For item types that do not support multiple columns, these will be ignored. If adding additional display columns ensure that the return column is included in the column list. The return column can be set to Visible No and Searchable No if you do not want it displayed to users.*

Example using emp/dept sample data:

- Create a list of values on table emp with return `empno` and display `ename`. Save.
- Edit the LOV and click *Additional Display Columns > Select Columns*. Select `job` as additional column.
- In the IG, set *Visible* and *Searchable* to "No" and Apply Changes.
- On the page, create 2 page items: `P1_EMPNO` (type popup LOV) and `P1_JOB` (type Text Field)
- For `P1_EMPNO`, pick the LOV created above as shared component > List Of Values and add `JOB:P2_JOB` under *Settings > Additional Output*. JOB is the additional column name/alias and P2_JOB is the item it should map to.
- Now when you run the page, observe that `P1_JOB` is populated when you select a value for `P1_EMPNO`

Comment: thx @Koen, this helped me get it working, but i realize i lose the ability to have the LOV source use dynamic SQL by setting it up in Shared Components vs. just using a SQL statement (or package function that returns SQL string). I'll have to rethink my design a bit. If the 'application form's' `AI_FLOW_TYPE = NEW` i want to use `LOV_NEW`, if the `AI_FLOW_TYPE = RENEW` - i want to use the `LOV_RENEW`. Will keep playing around

Comment: You could make your shared component query dependent on the page item - that works. SELECT ... FROM table WHERE :AI_FLOW_TYPE = 'NEW' UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM table WHERE :AI_FLOW_TYPE = 'RENEW'. That way you can benefit from this feature. Didn't test this but it should work.